# QGIS 2.18.18 : The following layers were not correctly generated

Tags: qgis

I've been trying to create an auto-input script for a model I'm using at work, given that I'm supposed to fix some errors and I've had enough of inputting layers manually for each run.
Here is the last, over-simplified version I've tried, and it is still not working:

```
    ##output_folder=folder

##t_sitetech=output vector
##CH=output vector
##BPE=output vector
##CB=output vector
##TEC=output vector
##ST=output vector
##POL=output vector
##t_zsro=output vector
##t_znro=output vector
##t_ptech=output vector
##t_cheminement=output vector
##t_adresse=output vector
##ADRESSES=output vector
##FichierLocal=output vector
##Code_NRO=output string
##Code_SRO=output string
##NomDuSRO=output string

#IMPORT
from qgis.utils import iface

for layer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    if "_CH" in str(layer.name()):
        CH = layer
    elif "_BPE" in str(layer.name()):
        BPE = layer
    elif "_CB" in str(layer.name()):
        CB = layer
    elif "_POL" in str(layer.name()):
        POL = layer
    elif "t_zsro" in str(layer.name()):
        t_zsro = layer
    elif "t_znro" in str(layer.name()):
        t_znro = layer
    elif "t_ptech" in str(layer.name()):
        t_ptech = layer
    elif "t_adresse" in str(layer.name()):
        t_adresse = layer
    elif "t_sitetech" in str(layer.name()):
        t_sitetech = layer
    elif "t_cheminement" in str(layer.name()):
        t_cheminement = layer
    elif "ADRESSES" in str(layer.name()):
        ADRESSES = layer
    elif "_TEC" in str(layer.name()):
        TEC = layer
        NomDuSRO = str(layer.name())[-10:-7] #Coefficient NomDuSRO
        NomDuSRO = int(NomDuSRO)*5+5 #Real SRO number
        NomDuSRO = str(NomDuSRO) + "1" #add 1 to the right
        NomDuSRO = NomDuSRO.ljust(10,"0") #fill with zeroes up to 10char
        NomDuSRO = str("'" + NomDuSRO + "'") #add quotes
        print ("NomDuSRO: " + NomDuSRO) #DEBUG
        for nro in TEC.getFeatures():
            Code_NRO = nro.attributes()[TEC.fieldNameIndex("CODE_ST_NR")]
            print("Code_NRO: " + str(Code_NRO)) #DEBUG
            Code_SRO = nro.attributes()[TEC.fieldNameIndex("CODE_TEC")]
            print("Code_SRO: " + str(Code_SRO)) #DEBUG

print CH
print BPE
print CB
print POL
print t_zsro
print t_znro
print t_ptech
print t_adresse
print t_sitetech
print t_cheminement
print ADRESSES
print TEC
```

And here is the error I get :

> Démarrage de l'algorithme [Unnamed algorithm] ... Converting outputs
>   Charger les couches de résultat
>
> The following layers were not correctly generated. t sitetech CH BPE
>   CB TEC POL t zsro t znro t ptech t cheminement t adresse ADRESSES You
>   can check the log messages to find more information about the
>   execution of the algorithm

What have I been doing wrong ?

EDIT : I'm having the same problems with another custom script, the symptoms are the same.

```
    #ID
##delete_other_sro=name
##Distri_GraceTHD=group

#INPUT
##sroIn=vector polygon
##adresseIn=vector point
##stIn=vector point
##codeNRO=string
##codeSRO=string

#OUTPUT
##sroOut=output vector polygon
##adresseOut=output vector point
##stOut=output vector point

#IMPORT
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

#LOADING LAYERS
sroOut = QgsVectorLayer(sroIn, "delete_sro_sro", "ogr")
adresseOut = QgsVectorLayer(adresseIn, "delete_sro_adresse", "ogr")
stOut = QgsVectorLayer(stIn, "delete_sro_sitetech", "ogr")

#REMOVING QUOTES FROM INPUT CODE
codeNRO = codeNRO.replace("'","")
codeSRO = codeSRO.replace("'","")

#STEP 1: REMOVE USELESS SRO ZONES
sroOut.startEditing()
for zone in sroOut.getFeatures():
    if str(zone.attributes()[sroOut.fieldNameIndex("zs_refpm")]) not in codeSRO:
        sroOut.deleteFeature(zone.id())
sroOut.commitChanges()

#DEBUG
#Only 1 should remain
print("ZSRO: ONLY ONE SHOULD REMAIN")
for zone in sroOut.getFeatures():
    print zone

#STEP 2: AGAIN FOR SITETECH
stOut.startEditing()
for site in stOut.getFeatures():
    if str(site.attributes()[stOut.fieldNameIndex("st_codeext")]) not in [codeNRO, codeSRO]:
        stOut.deleteFeature(site.id())
stOut.commitChanges()

#DEBUG
#Only 2 should remain
print("SITETECH: ONLY TWO SHOULD REMAIN")
for site in stOut.getFeatures():
    print site

#STEP 3: AGAIN FOR ADRESSES
#3.1: Create a buffer around sitetech for tolerance (10cm)
buff = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', stOut, 0.1, 72.0, True, None)
stBuffed = QgsVectorLayer(buff['OUTPUT'], "delete_sro_st_buffed", "ogr")

#3.2: Delete all adresses that do not intersect a sitetech
adresseOut.startEditing()
for adr in adresseOut.getFeatures():
    for site in stBuffed.getFeatures():
        if not site.geometry().intersects(adr.geometry()):
            adresseOut.deleteFeature(adr.id())
adresseOut.commitChanges

#DEBUG
#Only 2 should remain
print("ADRESSE: ONLY TWO SHOULD REMAIN")
for adr in adresseOut.getFeatures():
    print adr
```

This one makes a few other algorithms fail, for instance "GRASS v.to.point" or "Clip (list index out of range)"

I'm guessing it has something to do with the outputs ? Maybe i'm not writing them properly for modeler use ?

Comment: Did you check the log for the actual error message?

Comment: I'm still having the same problems with other custom scripts used as modeler algorithms... I tried the same model with both manual and auto input => only the manual input works smoothly, auto-input does not pop errors on it's own but makes other modeler algorithms go crazy every one in a while, for example v.to.point (wrong paramater GRASS-REGION-PARAMETER) or clip (list index out of range). I think something is wrong with the output...